# how to show image with out symbol

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

hi guys i am trying submit form and get a result as jpeg on same page. how ever when click to submit button 
i get the some weird code instead of image hcan you guys help me here is my code

```
function xgetbarcode()
  {
$.get('ajax_barcode.php', { barcode: $('form[name=getbarcodeform] input[name=barcode]').val(), 
getarticlenumber: $('form[name=getbarcodeform] input[name=getarticlenumber]').val(),
},
         function(output)
     {
        $('#getbarcodee').html(output).show();  
      });
  }
<form>....
<input type="button" value="barcode" onclick="xgetbarcode();">
 </form>   

<div id="getbarcodee">here i get some weird symbol</div>
```

thanks a lot

Comment: It would be helpful to see what ajax_barcode.php does.

Answer (score 1):

Add a header to your php file

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

and add image into div with the source to your php file

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you are returning an image from ajax_getbarcode.php, and inserting the image (binary data) into the HTML. You need to use an `<img>` tag for displaying an image in HTML.

I suggest the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function xgetbarcode()
  {
    var image = '<img src="ajax_getbarcode.php?barcode=' + $('form[name=getbarcodeform] input[name=barcode]').val() + '&amp;getarticlenumber=' + $('form[name=getbarcodeform] input[name=getarticlenumber]').val() + '"/>';

    $(#getbarcodee).html(image).show();
  }
</script>

<form name="getbarcodeform"> ....
<input type="button" value="barcode" onclick="xgetbarcode();">
</form>

<div id="getbarcodee"></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help but i am getting some syntax error when i am trying to implement your idea

Answer (score 0):

What are you returning from your ajax_barcode.php?
Image name like xyz.jpeg

you supposed to return html tag like

```
<img src="xyz.jpg" width="" height="" />
```

Because .html() replace the entire text element of it's parent.